# DDD, CQRS - Identity service and user avatar (image) handling

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm designing an Identity Service using DDD and CQRS pattern. So far I have one aggregate `User` that has all the logic for changing user's state (creating, resetting password, confirming email, etc.). In my understanding, user's avatar is also part of his identity and should be handled in the context.

I've decided that such small pictures can be saved directly to the database, but I'm not sure how to design it inside the domain (or whether it should belong to the domain at all).

`Avatar` could in fact be modelled as an `Entity` and referenced in `User` aggregate by its ID, like that:

```
public class Avatar: Entity<AvatarId>
{
    AvatarId Id { get; } // Strongly typed ID
    byte[] Picture { get; private set; }
    AvatarExtension Extension { get; private set; } // Enumeration: JPG, PNG, GIF, etc.

    public void ChangePicture(byte[] newPicture, AvatarExtension newExtension)
    {
        // Ommited parameters validation for brevity
        Picture = newPicture;
        Extension = newExtension;
    }
}
```

```
public class User: IAggregateRoot, Entity<UserId>
{
    ...
    AvatarId AvatarId { get; } //Avatar referenced by ID

    public void SetAvatar(AvatarId avatarId)
    {
        AvatarId = avatarId;
    }
}
```

I'm afraid it leaks some infrastructure concerns, `Avatar` seems more like a table definition in EF Core (code-first). In addition, `Avatar` would require to has its own repository, because it has to be handled separately (added to `DdContext` etc. before creating `User`), but this is not an aggregate root and my gut feeling is that it shouldn't be. Maybe referencing `Avatar` directly as an object in `User` and keeping it as one-to-one relationship would be a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an aggregate (especially in CQRS) is validating commands, so the only state in an aggregate should be that for which there exists a command which would be rejected (resp. accepted) but would be accepted (resp. rejected) if the state changed.

It's hard to see how the bytes of an avatar would affect whether a future command against a user is accepted or rejected.  That a user has an avatar?  Sure, but that doesn't depend on the content of the avatar (a reference, e.g. a URL, to the avatar would suffice).  That no two users can have the same avatar?  That's not something the user aggregate modeling a single user can enforce (setting aside what exactly is meant by "no two can have the same avatar").

Comment: You're right, avatar is something optional that does not affect the business logic in any way. But then should in your opinion the user AR hold any reference to the avatar? Can updating it still be handled in a command or rather only an external service that would validate and save an avatar?

Comment: Handling the avatar itself is probably another service.  The association of a user with an avatar could be part of the user service or some other service.  So updating it could be a process of "upload avatar, get URL at which the uploaded avatar can be found, update user (or user -> avatar service if decomposing that way)"